# I am not able to buy testnet tokens in Goerli testnet. Even the testlinks are not shown

Tags: metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp, testnets, goerli

This is the transaction hash for testlinks transaction
0xe1a2efca71e333e4b0b8b81f2e109a305905fdf29158bc5f83a935663dccdffd

Answer (score 1):

No need to buy anything, you can just request goerli test eth here:
https://goerlifaucet.com/

You will need to have an alchemy account, but just tested it and got 0.2 eth in a few seconds!

Hope this helps!